# rbenv install 2.2.2 build failed on OSX El Capitan

Tags: ruby, macos, homebrew, rbenv

I'm trying to install ruby 2.2.2 on El Capitan, but failed, I got the message:

```
Downloading ruby-2.2.2.tar.gz...
-> http://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/5ffc0f317e429e6b29d4a98ac521c3ce65481bfd22a8cf845fa02a7b113d9b44
Installing ruby-2.2.2...

BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.11 using ruby-build 20150719)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/g_/4xc3skhj31g89q7z_czb4rx40000gn/T/ruby-build.20150723233128.20256
Results logged to /var/folders/g_/4xc3skhj31g89q7z_czb4rx40000gn/T/ruby-build.20150723233128.20256.log

Last 10 log lines:
    from /private/var/folders/g_/4xc3skhj31g89q7z_czb4rx40000gn/T/ruby-build.20150723233128.20256/ruby-2.2.2/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /private/var/folders/g_/4xc3skhj31g89q7z_czb4rx40000gn/T/ruby-build.20150723233128.20256/ruby-2.2.2/lib/rubygems.rb:556:in `install'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:722:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:721:in `each'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:721:in `block in <main>'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:757:in `call'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:757:in `block in <main>'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:754:in `each'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:754:in `<main>'
make: *** [do-install-all] Error 1
```

I have homebrew and I updated my xcode to xcode beta 7

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: Check if you have installed command-line tools.

Comment: @RMilushev I think I do, when I type "xcode-select --install" in terminal, I got this message: xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates

Comment: @RMilushev I also updated the command line tool, there's no updates available now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by upgrading openssl using `brew upgrade openssl`